# JPA @ManyToMany handling records

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many

I have two database tables. 
An *Enterpise* can have multiple *Employees* and an *Employee* can work in multiple *Enterprises*.

*Entrerprise.java*

```
@Entity
public class Enterprise{
   @id
   public Long id;

   public String enterpriseName;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "enterpriseList")
   public List<Employee> employeeList;
}
```

*Employee.java*

```
@Entity
public class Employee
{
    @id
    public Long id;

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public Integer age;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<Enterprise> enterpriseList;
}
```

How could I update some changes between *Enterprise* and *Employee*. Which is the best way considers the performance?

Assumed I want to update en *Employee* entity and have a list containing the id's of the associated enterprises. What should I do?

**EDIT**

I make an example:
In my database I have 4 enterprises

```
Ep1 -> id 1
Ep2 -> id 2
Ep3 -> id 3
Ep4 -> id 4
```

and an employee which works in *Ep2*.

Now the *Employee* gets some jobs in *Ep1* and *Ep4*.
That means, I receive the following data.

```
employeeID = 1
enterpriseList = [1,2,4]
```

Now, can I use an update query?

The solution I use at the moment is:

```
// get employee
Employee employee = entityHandlerService.getEmployeeById(employeeID);

// idList -> [1,2,4]
for(Long id : idList)
{
    // prevent duplicate
    if(employee.enterpriseList.stream().filter(e -> e.id.equals(id)).count() == 0)
    {
       // add enterprise to employee
       Enterprise enterpise = entityHandlerService.getEnterpriseById(id);
       employee.enterpriseList.add(enterprise);
    }
}
```

Comment: Either merge both entities after either one is updated using the `merge()` function, or set cascade to `merge` in the `@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)`

Comment: That I know, but how should I generate the LIST? Should I loop over my ID list and send a GET request to the database to receive the object reference?